# stopping anchor scrolling on key press using smoothscroll.js

Tags: anchor, smooth-scrolling

I'm trying to get a nice easing scroll effect on my site using smoothscroll.js from http://cferdinandi.github.io/smooth-scroll/ (shown as code below) and it works fine. However, scrolling with mousewheel while that's in effect causes the page to jitter all over the place because there are two animations taking place - the one from the the mousewheel and the other from the anchor scroll. So I'd like to either disable mousewheel on the anchor scroll animation or disable the anchor scroll animation on mousewheel. I'm not sure how to alter the code to do that. I'm pretty sure I should just be able to add a line or two to the code below but I've been trying for many hours and I can't get anything to work.

```
/* =============================================================

Smooth Scroll 3.2
Animate scrolling to anchor links, by Chris Ferdinandi.
http://gomakethings.com

Easing support contributed by Willem Liu.
https://github.com/willemliu

Easing functions forked from Gaëtan Renaudeau.
https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294

URL history support contributed by Robert Pate.
https://github.com/robertpateii

Fixed header support contributed by Arndt von Lucadou.
https://github.com/a-v-l

Infinite loop bugs in iOS and Chrome (when zoomed) by Alex Guzman.
https://github.com/alexguzman

Free to use under the MIT License.
http://gomakethings.com/mit/

* ============================================================= */

window.smoothScroll = (function (window, document, undefined) {

'use strict';

// Feature Test
if ( 'querySelector' in document && 'addEventListener' in window && Array.prototype.forEach ) {

    // SELECTORS

    var scrollToggles = document.querySelectorAll('[data-scroll]');


    // METHODS

    // Run the smooth scroll animation
    var runSmoothScroll = function (anchor, duration, easing, url) {

        // SELECTORS

        var startLocation = window.pageYOffset;

        // Get the height of a fixed header if one exists
        var scrollHeader = document.querySelector('[data-scroll-header]');
        var headerHeight = scrollHeader === null ? 0 : scrollHeader.offsetHeight;

        // Set the animation variables to 0/undefined.
        var timeLapsed = 0;
        var percentage, position;


        // METHODS

        // Calculate the easing pattern
        var easingPattern = function (type, time) {
            if ( type == 'easeInQuad' ) return time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity
            if ( type == 'easeOutQuad' ) return time * (2 - time); // decelerating to zero velocity
            if ( type == 'easeInOutQuad' ) return time < 0.5 ? 2 * time * time : -1 + (4 - 2 * time) * time; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
            if ( type == 'easeInCubic' ) return time * time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity
            if ( type == 'easeOutCubic' ) return (--time) * time * time + 1; // decelerating to zero velocity
            if ( type == 'easeInOutCubic' ) return time < 0.5 ? 4 * time * time * time : (time - 1) * (2 * time - 2) * (2 * time - 2) + 1; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
            if ( type == 'easeInQuart' ) return time * time * time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity
            if ( type == 'easeOutQuart' ) return 1 - (--time) * time * time * time; // decelerating to zero velocity
            if ( type == 'easeInOutQuart' ) return time < 0.5 ? 8 * time * time * time * time : 1 - 8 * (--time) * time * time * time; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
            if ( type == 'easeInQuint' ) return time * time * time * time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity
            if ( type == 'easeOutQuint' ) return 1 + (--time) * time * time * time * time; // decelerating to zero velocity
            if ( type == 'easeInOutQuint' ) return time < 0.5 ? 16 * time * time * time * time * time : 1 + 16 * (--time) * time * time * time * time; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration
            return time; // no easing, no acceleration
        };

        // Update the URL
        var updateURL = function (url, anchor) {
            if ( url === 'true' && history.pushState ) {
                history.pushState( {pos:anchor.id}, '', '#' + anchor.id );
            }
        };

        // Calculate how far to scroll
        var getEndLocation = function (anchor) {
            var location = 0;
            if (anchor.offsetParent) {
                do {
                    location += anchor.offsetTop;
                    anchor = anchor.offsetParent;
                } while (anchor);
            }
            location = location - headerHeight;
            if ( location >= 0 ) {
                return location;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        };
        var endLocation = getEndLocation(anchor);
        var distance = endLocation - startLocation;

        // Stop the scrolling animation when the anchor is reached (or at the top/bottom of the page)
        var stopAnimation = function () {
            var currentLocation = window.pageYOffset;
            if ( position == endLocation || currentLocation == endLocation || ( (window.innerHeight + currentLocation) >= document.body.scrollHeight ) ) {
                clearInterval(runAnimation);
            }
        };

        // Scroll the page by an increment, and check if it's time to stop
        var animateScroll = function () {
            timeLapsed += 16;
            percentage = ( timeLapsed / duration );
            percentage = ( percentage > 1 ) ? 1 : percentage;
            position = startLocation + ( distance * easingPattern(easing, percentage) );
            window.scrollTo( 0, position );
            stopAnimation();
        };


        // EVENTS, LISTENERS, AND INITS

        updateURL(url, anchor);
        var runAnimation = setInterval(animateScroll, 16);

    };

    // Check that anchor exists and run scroll animation
    var handleToggleClick = function (event) {

        // SELECTORS

        // Get anchor link and calculate distance from the top
        var dataID = this.getAttribute('href');
        var dataTarget = document.querySelector(dataID);
        var dataSpeed = this.getAttribute('data-speed');
        var dataEasing = this.getAttribute('data-easing');
        var dataURL = this.getAttribute('data-url');


        // EVENTS, LISTENERS, AND INITS

        event.preventDefault();
        if (dataTarget) {
            runSmoothScroll( dataTarget, dataSpeed || 500, dataEasing || 'easeInOutCubic', dataURL || 'false' );
        }

    };


    // EVENTS, LISTENERS, AND INITS

    // When a toggle is clicked, run the click handler
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(scrollToggles, function (toggle, index) {
        toggle.addEventListener('click', handleToggleClick, false);
    });

    // Return to the top of the page when back button is clicked and no hash is set
    window.onpopstate = function (event) {
        if ( event.state === null && window.location.hash === '' ) {
            window.scrollTo( 0, 0 );
        }
    };

}

})(window, document);
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out - I added

```
 $("html").bind("scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup", function(){
    clearInterval(runAnimation);
 });
```

directly under

```
var runSmoothScroll = function (anchor, duration, easing, url) {
```

as runSmoothScroll is the function called to run the scrolling animation. So whenever that function is called, it adds the function for ending the animation, clearInterval(runAnimation) to the mousewheel. I also figured out a way to get the script to temporarily disable mousewheel.

```
  /* =============================================================



Smooth Scroll 3.2

Animate scrolling to anchor links, by Chris Ferdinandi.

http://gomakethings.com



Easing support contributed by Willem Liu.

https://github.com/willemliu



Easing functions forked from Gaëtan Renaudeau.

https://gist.github.com/gre/1650294



URL history support contributed by Robert Pate.

https://github.com/robertpateii



Fixed header support contributed by Arndt von Lucadou.

https://github.com/a-v-l



Infinite loop bugs in iOS and Chrome (when zoomed) by Alex Guzman.

https://github.com/alexguzman



Free to use under the MIT License.

http://gomakethings.com/mit/



* ============================================================= */



window.smoothScroll = (function (window, document, undefined) {



'use strict';



// Feature Test

if ( 'querySelector' in document && 'addEventListener' in window && Array.prototype.forEach ) {



    // SELECTORS



    var scrollToggles = document.querySelectorAll('[data-scroll]');





    // METHODS



    // Run the smooth scroll animation

    var runSmoothScroll = function (anchor, duration, easing, url) {
        /*
        //2/23/2014 Figured out how to disable mousewheel for a set amount of time
        //disable mousewheel function
        $("html").bind("scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup", false);
        //pause until animated scrolling is finished, then enable mousewheel
        setTimeout(function(){
            $("html").unbind("scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup", false);
        }, duration);
        */


        //alternatively, can end the animation prematurely if mousewheel is used
        $("html, body").bind("scroll mousedown DOMMouseScroll mousewheel keyup", function(){
            clearInterval(runAnimation);
        });





        // SELECTORS



        var startLocation = window.pageYOffset;



        // Get the height of a fixed header if one exists

        var scrollHeader = document.querySelector('[data-scroll-header]');

        var headerHeight = scrollHeader === null ? 0 : scrollHeader.offsetHeight;



        // Set the animation variables to 0/undefined.

        var timeLapsed = 0;

        var percentage, position;





        // METHODS



        // Calculate the easing pattern

        var easingPattern = function (type, time) {

            if ( type == 'easeInQuad' ) return time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity

            if ( type == 'easeOutQuad' ) return time * (2 - time); // decelerating to zero velocity

            if ( type == 'easeInOutQuad' ) return time < 0.5 ? 2 * time * time : -1 + (4 - 2 * time) * time; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration

            if ( type == 'easeInCubic' ) return time * time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity

            if ( type == 'easeOutCubic' ) return (--time) * time * time + 1; // decelerating to zero velocity

            if ( type == 'easeInOutCubic' ) return time < 0.5 ? 4 * time * time * time : (time - 1) * (2 * time - 2) * (2 * time - 2) + 1; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration

            if ( type == 'easeInQuart' ) return time * time * time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity

            if ( type == 'easeOutQuart' ) return 1 - (--time) * time * time * time; // decelerating to zero velocity

            if ( type == 'easeInOutQuart' ) return time < 0.5 ? 8 * time * time * time * time : 1 - 8 * (--time) * time * time * time; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration

            if ( type == 'easeInQuint' ) return time * time * time * time * time; // accelerating from zero velocity

            if ( type == 'easeOutQuint' ) return 1 + (--time) * time * time * time * time; // decelerating to zero velocity

            if ( type == 'easeInOutQuint' ) return time < 0.5 ? 16 * time * time * time * time * time : 1 + 16 * (--time) * time * time * time * time; // acceleration until halfway, then deceleration

            return time; // no easing, no acceleration

        };



        // Update the URL

        var updateURL = function (url, anchor) {

            if ( url === 'true' && history.pushState ) {

                history.pushState( {pos:anchor.id}, '', '#' + anchor.id );

            }

        };



        // Calculate how far to scroll

        var getEndLocation = function (anchor) {

            var location = 0;

            if (anchor.offsetParent) {

                do {

                    location += anchor.offsetTop;

                    anchor = anchor.offsetParent;

                } while (anchor);

            }

            location = location - headerHeight;

            if ( location >= 0 ) {

                return location;

            } else {

                return 0;

            }

        };

        var endLocation = getEndLocation(anchor);

        var distance = endLocation - startLocation;



        // Stop the scrolling animation when the anchor is reached (or at the top/bottom of the page)

        var stopAnimation = function () {

            var currentLocation = window.pageYOffset;

            if ( position == endLocation || currentLocation == endLocation || ( (window.innerHeight + currentLocation) >= document.body.scrollHeight ) ) {

                clearInterval(runAnimation);

            }

        };



        // Scroll the page by an increment, and check if it's time to stop

        var animateScroll = function () {

            timeLapsed += 16;

            percentage = ( timeLapsed / duration );

            percentage = ( percentage > 1 ) ? 1 : percentage;

            position = startLocation + ( distance * easingPattern(easing, percentage) );

            window.scrollTo( 0, position );

            stopAnimation();

        };





        // EVENTS, LISTENERS, AND INITS



        updateURL(url, anchor);
        var runAnimation = setInterval(animateScroll, 16);



    };



    // Check that anchor exists and run scroll animation

    var handleToggleClick = function (event) {



        // SELECTORS



        // Get anchor link and calculate distance from the top

        var dataID = this.getAttribute('href');

        var dataTarget = document.querySelector(dataID);

        var dataSpeed = this.getAttribute('data-speed');

        var dataEasing = this.getAttribute('data-easing');

        var dataURL = this.getAttribute('data-url');





        // EVENTS, LISTENERS, AND INITS



        event.preventDefault();

        if (dataTarget) {

            runSmoothScroll( dataTarget, dataSpeed || 500, dataEasing || 'easeInOutCubic', dataURL || 'false' );

        }



    };





    // EVENTS, LISTENERS, AND INITS



    // When a toggle is clicked, run the click handler

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(scrollToggles, function (toggle, index) {

        toggle.addEventListener('click', handleToggleClick, false);

    });



    // Return to the top of the page when back button is clicked and no hash is set

    window.onpopstate = function (event) {

        if ( event.state === null && window.location.hash === '' ) {

            window.scrollTo( 0, 0 );

        }

    };



}



})(window, document);
```